# Order by views and time rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a table called images that contains a field called impressions_count and i want to order by impressions_count and images created one week ago.

I have tried this but it doesn't work properly, it only orders by the impressions_count.

```
@images = Image.unscoped.order("impressions_count DESC, created_at < ?", DateTime.now - 1.week).limit(10)


  Image Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "images".* FROM "images" ORDER BY impressions_count DESC, created_at < ?, '2013-03-07 16:49:50' LIMIT 10
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
@images = Image.unscoped.where('created_at > ?', 1.week.ago).order('impressions_count DESC')
```

Comment: @images = Image.unscoped.where('created_at > ?', DateTime.now - 1.week).order('impressions_count DESC')                             this worked, had to change the less than sign to a greater than, thanks :)

Comment: I think, the question is to give high priority to images created one week before for sorting. Is it correct ?

Comment: Just wanted to get images created one week ago and order them by views, thanks anyway